# how to get process description using WMI?

Tags: c#, process, wmi, wmi-query

I'm using WMI query to get a list of all processes, but what i missing is process description!
It appears like this when i use "Description" property!

```
Name : chrome.exe            Description : chrome.exe
```

but it should be

```
Name : chrome.exe            Description : Google Chrome
```

So what's the property name that return process description?

```
public void GetProcesses()
{ 
     ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_Process");
     ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();
     foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Name : {0}     Description : {1}",obj["Name"],obj["Description"]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not WMI, but will work for processes on your local machine.

You may find a description of a process [sic.], actually it is the description of the executable, using [GetVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo.aspx). Than check the FileDescription and or ProductName [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx).

Note however, that there is no guarantee that this information is available. Nevertheless it is probably your best bet. Other tools, like sysinternals process explorer, display that information as well.

Comment: well, im using WCF, client gets hostPC processes [ID,Name,Desc,WorkingSet] in a loop, do you think declaring a new GetVersionInfo each time in the loop is a good idea?

Comment: You have to call it per process/executable. But the value won't change, i.e. while you certainly want to return updated values for WorkingSet, you don't need to do so for the version info - you could cache it. Whether that is actually worth the trouble, compared to just calling it every time, is a little hard to say. You'd have to do some measurements and of course it depends on how often the client calls the server (and thus invokes `GetVersionInfo` per executable.

Comment: I've figured a way out, i call it once when i get the list of processes, i only update if a new process launched or closed. thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You have all the properties in the [Win32_Process class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Looks like you're out of luck, testing some processes on my machine using [wbemtest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692770.aspx), I don't see any property that suits you needs. It's possible that processes don't expose such information.

Comment: actually before i used WMI, i was able to get Description using `System. Diagnostics`, and in windows task manager its also shows description !!

Comment: If the process is local you have Christian.K's suggestion. I was just assuming we weren't talking local because of WMI. For local processes it makes much more sense to use System.Diagnostics.Process: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Comment: im working on client-server app, using `System.Diagnostics.Process` maybe faster, but it doesn't return the whole processes, you need to run as Admin to get most of them, and you need to have two versions for your app to work on any computer (x86,x64) so i prefer to use WMI. Unfortunately there's always something missed.