# How would I get a process description (the one displayed in task manager) in VB express 2010

Tags: vb.net

Hello and thank you for your time. this is my first post so bear with me if I fail to provide something i should have.

I am trying to pull the full list of running tasks (ID, name , and description ) and place them in a viewlist. 
I started with

```
        For Each process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
        pid = process.Id
        ListView1.Items.Add(pid)
        With ListView1
            itm = .FindItemWithText(pid, False, 0, False)

            If Not itm Is Nothing Then
                count = itm.Index
            End If
        End With

        If (pid <> 0 And pid <> 4) Then
            ListView1.Items(count).SubItems.Add(process.ProcessName)
            'ListView1.Items(count).SubItems.Add(process.Id)
        Else
            If (pid = 0) Then
                ListView1.Items(count).SubItems.Add("Idle Process")
            End If
            If (pid = 4) Then
                ListView1.Items(count).SubItems.Add("SYSTEM")
            End If
        End If
```

which works   (I read i needed to make the exceptions for id 0 and 4)

so the issue i'm having is I can't find the description ( as shown in task manager) anywhere. 
I have tried description, caption, commandline, executablepath, but none of these match the description field in task manager.

for example :  there is a process called dllhost  task manager gives the description as "COM  Surrogate"  I have been unable to find anything in process.xxxx or going the other route and using a wmi call. any thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: Check out this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10570965/945456

Comment: @derek yes I looked into wmi calls but none of them see to show the information i am looking for. The Caption and Description strings are usually the exe filename not the description listed in task manager.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is for can be done through `FileVersionInfo` Class.
Have a try:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim p As New Process
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\windows\System32\mspaint.exe"
        Dim FileInfoVersion As FileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(p.StartInfo.FileName)
        MsgBox(FileInfoVersion.FileDescription)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It got me must further along than i was.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It got me must further along than i was. 
when I used 
`Dim FileInfoVersion As FileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(p.StartInfo.FileName)`

it would fail on some processes with "filenotfoundexception was unhandled"

so i placed it inside a catch and filled the failure with a dummy string
so things that failed are  spoolsv, winlogon,nvsvc, conhost and the like. 
now conhost for example shows "console window host" in task manager but get the exception in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to find the full path of spoolsv, mspaint, etc.

You can try calling GetFullPath( "mspaint.exe" ).

NOTE: you need to use "mspaint.exe", not just "mspaint".

On my system, it returns: C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe

```
Public Shared Function GetFullPath(ByVal fileName As String) As String
    If File.Exists(fileName) Then
        Return Path.GetFullPath(fileName)
    End If
    Dim values As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")
    If (Not (values) Is Nothing) Then
        For Each dirName As String In values.Split(";".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.None)
            Dim fullPath As String = Path.Combine(dirName, fileName)
            If File.Exists(fullPath) Then
                Return fullPath
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I tried getting the full path via process.mainmodule.filename    with a catch  (since some processes are 64 bit and 32 bit can not read 64 bit mainmodule data )  that uses a wmi call to pull executablepath 

either way I do get a full file path 
conhost  returns  c:\windows\system32\conhost.exe which is what I plug into p.StartInfo.FileName = file   but it still fails  (using try ) so my catch picks it up and returns "error" & the path  (from above ) so I can see that it failed and the file name was actually there.